# java code for comparing a string value with a jtable value and done updation based on that comparisons result

Tags: java

My goal is to check the text field  value with JTable content. If it matches with  the table content then the count of that text field value will be increased by one. **For example** I enter a product  in to JTable, if  I again try to enter the same item, then the product count must be changed to 'two'.
Please help me i want java coding.....
I try this coding,

```
class HighlightRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col){
        JLabel l = (JLabel)super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col
        );
        if (isSelected){
            // don't change the color for selected cells
            return l;
        }
        String valString = (value == null ? null : value.toString());
        if (str.equals(valString)){
            l.setBackground(Color.yellow); // or any other color
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better manage if Items, Products etc exists already using querys on a database and recharging the Table if necessary.
You can simulate a database with one List<> with every item in it.

### Possible solution without using events:

Recommend use DefaultTableModel for this, and not the JTable

Use a fori for every table row getting the value which you want to compare

```
    `for(){
    if(yourStringInput.equals(table.getValueAt(row(i),column).toString()){
    //The value which you want update
    int count=(Integer)table.getValueAt(row,column);
    table.setValueAt(count,row(i),column);
    }
    }`
```

JTable api:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html